# UICollectionView with dynamic cell content - get cell to remember state

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that contains dynamic content. The problem I am having is that when the cell is `dequeued` it forgets its state. In my `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I have a boolean value that when it is true, it changes to a true image, but when it is false, it changes to a false image. However when I scroll down and back up, the cells forget there state. Is there a way to make a cell remember its state? Here is what is inside my

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   

    SalesCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    SaleImage * saleImage = [self.SaleObjs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:saleImage.imageName];
    if (saleImage.isBookable) {
        cell.isBookable = YES;
    }
    else{
        cell.isBookable=NO;
    }

return cell;
}
```

I have a remedy for this but it effects performance. I add this to my custom cell;

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];


    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Here is my collection view cell;

```
@implementation SalesCollectionViewCell


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // Initialization code
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
        self.bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self.book = [[UILabel alloc] init];      
        [self.contentView insertSubview:self.bgImageView atIndex:0];


         return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{

    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.isBookable) {
        self.book.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height - 41, 140, 41);
        self.book.text = @"Book this Item";
        self.book.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.book.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
        self.book.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.book.backgroundColor= [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        self.book.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFont size:17.0];
        [self.contentView insertSubview:self.book atIndex:2];

        self.bgImageView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, self.bounds.size.height - self.book.bounds.size.height);


    }
    else{
        self.bgImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    }



}

-(void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.book removeFromSuperview];
    [self setNeedsLayout];


}
```

Comment: Strange, your collection view doesn't have "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier" in the cellForItem in the above source code. Your saleImage.isBookable property should already handle the state, is the isBookable property ever changed?

Comment: @Zhang Sorry that was a typo, please see the above edit. The isBookable property is different for each cell. So some may be bookable, and others are not. What happens is when a bookable cell is reused with the contents of a nonbookable item, the bookable image remains.

Comment: @Zhang it correctly handles the bookable state when the views are present on the screen, but if i scroll down (so the top cells leave the screen) and scroll back, the non bookable objects have the bookable image.

Comment: Try setting your image = nil; before checking the if() condition in the cellForItemAtIndex, see if that clears the image.

Comment: @Zhang Unfortunately it didnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @iphonic said, the `isBookable` property should be (re)moved from the cell completely. Cells in a UICollectionView are being reused most of the time, so even though your saleImage.isBookable is in the correct state your cell.isBookable is probably not.

I would do the following:

```
if(saleImage.isBookable){
  self.bgImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, self.bounds.size.height - self.book.bounds.size.height);
  cell.bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:saleImage.imageName];
  cell.book.hidden = NO;
}
else{
 self.bgImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
 cell.bgImageView.image = nil;
 cell.book.hidden = YES;
}

[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

inside `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.

I would also have finished setting up the book `UILabel` inside initWithFrame and have it initially hidden. Something like:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
    self.bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [self.contentView insertSubview:self.bgImageView atIndex:0];

    self.book = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height - 41, 140, 41)];      

    self.book.text = @"Book this Item";
    self.book.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.book.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    self.book.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.book.backgroundColor= [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.book.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFont size:17.0];
    self.book.hidden = YES;

    [self.contentView insertSubview:self.book atIndex:2];
}
```

Then you would not need to override `layoutSubviews`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Cells should not "remember" their state; collection view or table view **data source** should. In the respective `cellForIndexPath` method, you should set the **current state** of the cell and let it configure itself as needed.

Comment: Adding into the answer, move `isBookable` property to `SaleImage` class from cell.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
  [super prepareForReuse];
  self.isBookable = nil;
  [self.book removeFromSuperview];
  [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Try setting `isBookable` to nil. I'm assuming that the cell is setting its layout with the previous cell's `isBookable` value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd override `isBookable` setter in the cell class:

```
- (void) setIsBookable:(BOOL)isBookable
{
    BOOL needsLayout = isBookable != _isBookable;
    _isBookable = isBookable;
    if(needsLayout)
    {
        [self.book removeFromSuperview];
        [self setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```

Also I'd recommend change `@property (nonatomic) BOOL isBookable;` with `@property (nonatomic, getter = isBookable) BOOL bookable;` in order to follow Apple Code Convention.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two types of cells with different identifiers:

```
     static NSString *Bookable = @"Bookable";
     static NSString *NonBookable = @"NonBookable";
     NSString *currentIdentifier;
     if(saleImage.isBookable)//isBookable property must be set in SaleImage class
     {
          currentIdentifier = Bookable;
     }
     else{
          currentIdentifier = NonBookable;
     }


     SalesCollectionViewCell *cell = (SalesCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:currentIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

1st - Save/keep the indexPath of the cell that is changed.

2nd -

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   

    SalesCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath == self.changedIndexPath)
        [cell trueImage];
    else
        [cell falseImage];
return cell;
}
```

Inside the cell, you just implement the `-(void) trueImage` and the `- (void) falseImage` which changes the image inside the cell.

I hope I helped :)